# Local node.js app works fine on localhost but not from external access

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an app on my local computer which works perfectly fine if I access it via http://localhost:8080. I have forwarded the port on my router. However, when I access http://some-dynamic-dns:8080 I can only see an empty site with my background-image loaded (basically what is inside the /client/index.html), but the app doesn't run.

My app is based on this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-multiplayer-card-game-with-phaser-3-express-and-socket-io/

Any suggestions on how to let people connect from the web to my local computer?

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.listen(8080);
app.use(express.static('./client/'));
```

**folder structure:**

```
my-app-folder
    client
    node-modules
    server.js
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "jass",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you open up the developer tools, what errors do you see?

Comment: None. If I access the page over the dynamic-dns link, It just loads the /client/index.html (which only contains the basic html-structure).

Comment: And how does this differ from visiting the site via localhost?

Comment: localhost displays my full running card game, which i can play perfectly fine with multiple browser-tabs on my computer that connect to localhost

Comment: Is the loaded HTML the same on both sites?

Comment: are you able to access it over the LAN through another device?

Comment: The site looks the same if I access it from LAN and from the web.
I think localhost renders my index.js file which is under /client/src/index.js.

Comment: Can you try hosting it on heroku and see if that works?

Comment: I guess it is just too big of a mess because it is based on the tutorial linked above. I'll probably try and set up a new clean project.. Thanks anyway for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

May I know how you are trying to access this page from a public network? If you are trying to access from the domain, in that case you must have public IP.

You can check the following workarounds :

1. check if correct public IP pointed from domain.
2. check if port is opened from the firewall. If it is not getting blocked from the firewall.
3. check if router/port forwarding rule is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your not getting any errors on the page, if your server is running on linux insure that chmod has the propper permissions for you website. That could be what is causing the issue.

is your phaser game code in your html file, or is it in it's own js file?